# Using \cite{} and \citep{} in alphabetic order (in-text)

Tags: bibtex

I have the regular setup for references from the Overleaf website. As I understand it, when multiple references are cited, the in-text citations follow the writing order, but not automatically an alphabetic order?

Would be glad about this solution (in-text parentheses citation alphabetic order)

Edit: I post a MWE. Here, Ridley should go to the end, because R is after B.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=2.5cm,textwidth=16.5cm,top=2cm, bottom=2cm, textheight=27cm}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} 
    
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \citep{bhat2022, ridley2020, bharadwaj2017}. 
\newpage
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{references.bib}
%\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And the references are:

```
@article{bharadwaj2017,
  title={Mental health stigma},
  author={Bharadwaj, Prashant and Pai, Mallesh M and Suziedelyte, Agne},
  journal={Economics Letters},
  volume={159},
  pages={57--60},
  year={2017},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}




@misc{bhat2022,
  type = {Working {{Paper}}},
  title = {The {{Long-Run Effects}} of {{Psychotherapy}} on {{Depression}}, {{Beliefs}}, and {{Economic Outcomes}}},
  author = {Bhat, Bhargav and {de Quidt}, Jonathan and Haushofer, Johannes and Patel, Vikram H. and Rao, Gautam and Schilbach, Frank and Vautrey, Pierre-Luc P.},
  year = {2022},
  month = may,
  series = {Working {{Paper Series}}},
  number = {30011},
  publisher = {{National Bureau of Economic Research}},
  doi = {10.3386/w30011},
}

@article{ridley2020,
  title = {Poverty, Depression, and Anxiety: {{Causal}} Evidence and Mechanisms},
  shorttitle = {Poverty, Depression, and Anxiety},
  author = {Ridley, Matthew and Rao, Gautam and Schilbach, Frank and Patel, Vikram},
  year = {2020},
  month = dec,
  journal = {Science},
  volume = {370},
  number = {6522},
  publisher = {{American Association for the Advancement of Science}},
  doi = {10.1126/science.aay0214},
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please add specific code to your question, there are many possible set-ups on overleaf.  You might be able to use the `cite` package to solve the problem in some situations.

Comment: \bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{bibliographyCiteDrive.bib}
And in the text:
\citep{callaway2021, goodmanbacon2021, santannaZhao2020}
These are not alphabetically ordered unless manually done so.

Comment: Thank you.  If you edit your question and complete the code to a minimal document that we can compile, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/15925 for some help. The details of the individual entries will also matter.

Comment: I have added all information for a MWE.

Comment: Try `\usepackage[sort]{natbib}` instead of `\usepackage{natbib}`.

Comment: Note that there are some edge cases where `natbib` and `apalike` don't fully work together. Plus the `apalike` is almost 35 years old and does not support many modern fields like `doi`. You may want to go for a more modern `natbib` style (`plainnat`, which is only 30 years old, but was periodically modernised up until the early 2000s).

Comment: I confirm that \usepackage[sort]{natbib} solves the problem.